# Url is opening even without form validation

Tags: javascript, validation, html

I've created a login page for a web page.after login user should be redirected to another page.But when you give the redirect url directly in browser,it opens.Its not supposed to be that way.Am i missing something here?.Am newbie,please help me out.I have done the form validation in javascript and opening the redirect url like in the code below

```
function check(form)
{
    if(form.userid.value == "myuserid" && form.pswrd.value == "mypswrd")
    {
        window.open('demo/index.html','_self')
            }
    else
    {
        alert("Error Password or Username")
    }
}
```

**Full code:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login page</title>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Login Page </h1>
        <form name="login">
            Username<input type="text" name="userid"/>
            Password<input type="password" name="pswrd"/>
            <input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/>
            <input type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
        </form>

    <script language="javascript" >
    function check(form)
    {
        if(form.userid.value == "myuserid" && form.pswrd.value == "mypswrd")
        {
            window.open('demo/index.html','_self')
        else
        {
            alert("Error Password or Username")
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you getting the alert box?

Comment: In onclick/onsubmit event of button you should call function `check` like following:
`return check(this)` 
and modify function `check` to return true or false based on the validation.

Comment: ya am getting that alert box and updated the above code.typo mistake while posting here

Comment: Show us more code or make a JSFiddle

Comment: Show more comment user

Comment: Change your code as @learningloop suggested

Comment: I've done that way.Still it is redirecting if i give url .../demo/index.html directly in browser

Comment: Remove all the javascript and just add a link to `demo/index.html` - it's as safe as it is now...

Comment: can you elaborate bit more?i didn't get your point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to prevent viewing a page without login, you should use cookie or session. It is available in php.

In java script, you can use `localstorage`

Modify your if condition as

```
if(form.userid.value == "myuserid" && form.pswrd.value == "mypswrd")
        {
            window.localStorage.setItem("Login", "true");
            window.open('demo/index.html','_self');

         }
```

and add the following script in your destination page, `demo/index.html`

```
window.onload=function(){
if(window.localStorage.getItem("Login")!="true") {
 alert("Please Login");
 window.open('login.html','_self');
}
};
```

Note : You will be able to access the destination page once you logged in. if you want to logout, under the logout, you should set the `login` item as `false` -

```
window.localStorage.setItem("Login", "false");
```

Or else, you can always access the page, if you have logged in for aleast one time.

Comment: The setsup function is not fired. you have missed the brackets. Try with this **<body onload = "setsup();">**

Comment: And also define the function with brackets `function setsup() {`

Comment: Thanks:) worked like a charm.One more question at first if user gives  the redirect url,it will open because localstorage value is not yet set.is there any other way to set it to default value as 'false'? so that it will work only after user login no matter what.

Comment: Sorry, i dont get you. what do you mean by **user gives the redirect url**

Comment: index.html file that was the redirect url here after user logs in

Comment: 1) On loading the page for the first time in the browser, the value of `Login` will be `undefined`. So fortunately, if the user enters the address of the home page in the browser, the condition `if(window.localStorage.getItem("Login")!="true")` becomes true, and redirects to `login` page.
2) If the user has logged in the browser, at least for once, then the code `window.localStorage.setItem("Login", "true");` in the form validation, sets the `Login` value as `true`. So after that, whenever the user enters the home page, he will remain in home page as the condition fails since `Login` is `true`

Comment: Ah! got it.Thanks for such detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not on this side but with the demo/book1/index.html page. Unless you add code there to prevent access to it you will always be able to open it in the browser. I think you need to investigate using some sort of framework that offers authentication out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Login page</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1> Login Page </h1>
  <form name="login">
     Username<input type="text" name="userid"/>
        Password<input type="password" name="pswrd"/>
        <input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/>
        <input type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
    </form>
    <script language="javascript" >
function check(form)
{
    if(form.userid.value == "Username" && form.pswrd.value == "Password")
    {
        window.open("http://www.google.com");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Error Password or Username")
    }
}
          </script>
 </body>
</html>
```